# User Id reference issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having issues with passing the user_id into the params by referencing it in a find_by. I have a pin number that a user will put in and what that does it gets checked to see if it is valid and if so then take that users id and place it in the params for saving in the database.

controller

```
class InventoriesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_inventory, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @inventories = Inventory.all
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @inventory = Inventory.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
      if @user = User.find_by(pin: params[:pin])
        @inventory = Inventory.new(inventory_params)
        @inventory.user_id = @user.id
        if @inventory.valid?
          @inventory.save

        else

        end
      else

      end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @inventory.update(inventory_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @inventory, notice: 'Inventory was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @inventory }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @inventory.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @inventory.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to inventories_url, notice: 'Inventory was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_inventory
      @inventory = Inventory.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def inventory_params
      params.require(:inventory).permit(:eq_type_id, :equipment_id, :chauffeur_id, :user_id)
    end

end
```

so this doesn't save can assume it's because user_id 1985 isn't a thing and when it gives me the error i see

> "inventory"=>{"eq_type_id"=>"1", "equipment_id"=>"1",
>   "chauffeur_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1985"}

which the incorrect way i want the user_id to be handled. It should be user_id: 1.

now, if i was to go into rails console and do

> user = User.find_by(pin: 1985)

I get a user object:

```
#<User id: 1, email: "myemail@email.com", created_at: "2017-08-11 18:39:22", updated_at: "2017-08-11 18:40:22", admin: true, pin: "1985">
```

then if I initiate the new inventory

> inventory = Inventory.new

I get the inventory object

```
#<Inventory id: nil, eq_type_id: nil, equipment_id: nil, chauffeur_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil>
```

I can then assign the user_id in the inventory object by

> inventory.user_id = user.id

and then look at the inventory object again, i can see it was assigned.

```
#<Inventory id: nil, eq_type_id: nil, equipment_id: nil, chauffeur_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 3>
```

now in the form the rest is filled in correctly and not showing "nil" but the user_id still comes up as 1985 for some reason. So I am not sure why in rails console it works but in the application it doesn't.

Comment: From which request you get the `params[:pin_number]`?

Comment: Also can you show the rest of the code? This line `if @user = User.find_by(pin_number: params[:pin_number])` is wrong btw

Comment: I would believe it would be a post.

Comment: Are you talking about the whole controller? or just the missing else blanks?

Comment: I mean is there any code above `if @user = User.find_by(pin_number: params[:pin_number])` in that particular method?

Comment: I just put the whole controller on there now.

Comment: Try removing `if` in this line `if @user = User.find_by(pin_number: params[:pin_number])` and remove the corresponding `end` for that `if `and check

Comment: i get an error page saying "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass" but at the bottom the parameters are still the same, still showing the user_id as 1985.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152658/discussion-between-allen-and-pavan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion, In your form you have

```
<%= form.label "Pin Number" %>
<%= form.text_field :user_id, id: :pin, class: "form-control" %>
```

So using `params[:pin_number]` is wrong as you used `:user_id` for `text_field`. It should be `params[:inventory][:user_id]`. Also you need to handle the failed save too. Your code should look like below.

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by(pin: params[:inventory][:user_id])
  @inventory = Inventory.new(inventory_params)
  @inventory.user_id = @user.id
  if @inventory.valid?
    @inventory.save
  else
    #write code to handle the failed save
  end
end
```

Comment: AH! so if the pin is wrong, it fails at the point of inventory.user_id = user.id saying it is nil, it wont even hit the if inventory.valid? part. Would i have to use an if statement on top of the other if statement?

Comment: @Allen Yes or just change that to `@inventory.user_id = @user.id if @user`